# Call the command before the delimiter or pipeline

Tags: bash, shell

If I run the command as below:

```
wget http://localhost.com/something.zip -O /tmp/out.zip; echo "I want to call the command that was executed before this command"
```

Or

```
wc -l somefile.txt | echo "how do I call this command on the left?"
```

What I want is that when I run the first command, I can call `wget http://localhost.com/something.zip -O /tmp/out.zip` as strings and call it using echo or whatever

Same as the second command, I also want to call `wc -l somefile.txt` and save it as a string and want to be able to call it

I've tried with commands like this

```
wget http://localhost.com/something.zip -O /tmp/out.zip; echo !:p
```

and also

```
wc -l somefile.txt | echo !:0
```

And there were no results like I wanted

```
command1; command2
command1 | command2
```

I want to be able to call command1 from command2, so for example I can put it in a txt file using:

```
wget http://localhost.com/something.zip -O /tmp/out.zip; echo $command1 > log.txt
cat log.txt
```

```
wget http://localhost.com/something.zip -O /tmp/out.zip
```

Comment: Store the command into an array. Expand the array as a command.

Comment: Your use of the word "call" is confusing -- to me it means the same thing as "execute", but you seem to be using it to mean "print".

Comment: You didn't mention what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you are looking for `set -x` to show you the commands that were executed.

Comment: Piping into `echo` does not make sense, since `echo` ignores its stdin.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it on the same line, but you can do it in two lines using history expansion:

```
wc -l somefile.txt
!!:p
```

`!!` expands to the previous command line. Putting `p` after the word designator (which is empty so no specific word is selected) prints it without executing it.

If you want to save it so you can print it later, you can assign to a variable:

```
wc -l somefile.txt
cmd=!!:q
echo "$cmd"
```

Here, the `q` modifier quotes the expansion so it will be a single word that gets assigned to the variable.

Comment: That said, the OP presumably wants to do this in a script (if it's on-topic, anyhow), and history expansion isn't available in scripts without some work you aren't presently demonstrating.

Comment: It's not too clear what the OP's goal is, so this may be an XY problem. I probably should have asked for clarification before answering.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do what you want is to use a DEBUG [trap](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap) to update variables that keep track of executed commands.  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates the idea:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

set -o functrace

prev_bash_command='' bash_command=''
trap 'prev_bash_command=$bash_command; bash_command=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG

echo wget http://localhost.com/something.zip -O /tmp/out.zip
printf 'previous command: %s\n' "$prev_bash_command"
```

The code outputs:

```
wget http://localhost.com/something.zip -O /tmp/out.zip
previous command: echo wget http://localhost.com/something.zip -O /tmp/out.zip
```

- `set -o functrace` causes the DEBUG trap to run inside functions and command substitutions.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I used `printf` instead of `echo` to output the previous command.

Comment: Note that the OP is looking for the command that is the prior stage _in a pipeline_, which is a bit different from the meaning of "previous" used here.

Comment: I don't think the pipeline is a necessity, that was just one of their attempted formulations. The first one was the previous command in a list. @CharlesDuffy